# Obtener el PromiseValue de una promesa

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que devuelve el contenido de un archivo html, pero me devuelve algo así:

```
Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: "<span>contendido</spab>"
```

Como podría obtener el `PromiseValue` para hacer un innerHTML

> Estoy claro que la promesa me la retorna `axios`

```js
const template = async(urlGet) => {
  const retorno = axios.get(urlGet).then((e) => {
    return e.data
  })
  return await retorno
}

console.log(template('miarchivo.html'))
```

Comment: intentá antes del .then coloca .then(res => res.json): ....axios.get(urlGet).then(res => res.json).then((e)......

Comment: Intenté pero me retorna: [[PromiseValue]]: undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clave era agregar `await` antes `axios.get()` para poder esperar que la promesa se haya ejecutado.

```js
const template = async(urlGet) => {
  const { data: retorno } = await axios.get(urlGet)
  return retorno
}

console.log(template('miarchivo.html'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a utiliza el operador de mapeo:

```
const template = async(urlGet) => {
  const retorno = axios.get(urlGet).map((e) => {
    return e.data
  })
  return await retorno
}

console.log(template('miarchivo.html'))
```